# Jquery sends a Get request to /false

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to write a file uploader and jquery sends a get request to /false which returns as a 404 obviously. What is jquery trying to do? Should i implement a service at /false.?

EDIT:

The request gets sent out as soon as i select a file to upload.
I'm using the jquery's file uploader plugin.

I dont think there is any variable for the url. But i'll check on it.

Comment: whoa, context, context. When does jQuery do this? From what script, what page? What code have you written? At what point is this request sent?

Comment: What does your code look like (ie how are you setting up the file uploader).

Comment: Please give us more information.

Comment: Please show some code. You most likely have a mistake somewhere.

Comment: is this your file uploader, or a third party? You're not going to do file uploads with an AJAX request. I know plugins do it by inserting IFRAMES with an input file field.

Comment: jQuery doesn't implements automatic services by himself, the error must be another thing, do you have a public url with the example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are using a variable name for where to send your request to, and for whatever reason that variable is literally `false`.  Change the variable value to where you want to send the request to.  That's my guess.

Comment: "It look like you're trying to use a variable name for your request location! Can I help you with that?"  :P

Comment: I guess I could change my avatar to a paperclip.

Comment: I checked on it. The variable is set to a string '/upload'

Comment: @Kasturi We'll need more information to help you more.  Could you post your JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: The Get request to /false happens in the demo page itself. How can i prevent it?